# Rails Beta3 & PaperClip & Passenger Bundler::PathError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, passenger, bundler, mod-rails

So I'm going around in circles with this - I'm using a fork of the Paperclip Rails gem to get it to work with Rails3. Works fine on my OSX box with Passenger. But on my server (CentOS 5) I get this this error:

`git://github.com/lmumar/paperclip.git (at rails3) is not checked out. Please run`bundle install`(Bundler::PathError)Blockquote`

I tried Bundle Pack, but that doesnt pack gems from github. I read a post about setting the parh to the BUNDLE_HOME in my application.rb file which I tried:

```
ENV['BUNDLER_HOME']="~/.bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/"
```

But that doesnt work. Any ideas anyone? I dont know what else to do and have no idea how to debug or trace the problem further :(

Passenger version 2.2.11.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, well, I dont really fully understand how to set the paths, but in the end I did:

```
export BUNDLE_PATH=$GEM_HOME
```

Despite much frackin' around I couldnt set the BUNDLE_PATH to the location in my home directory where it was installing the gem from Github.

So after I ran the above I just did 'bundle install' again and it's working. :/